# Merge if possible otherwise concat pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 df that I would like to combine where the first 3 columns are same data if exists, and columns afterwards are new from each of the df. For example df[3:] are different, than df2[3:]

I would like to merge them if they have the same unique identifier, otherwise I would like to concat.

df1

```
ID    A     B     2009   2010   
1     A     B        2      3
2     A     C        2      2
3     A     B        3      3
```

df2

```
ID    A     B     2011   2012   
2     A     C        2      2
3     A     C        3      4
5     A     B        8      9
```

df3

```
ID    A     B     2013   2014   
2     A     C        2      3
4     A     E        3      4
5     A     B        8      9
```

result df

```
ID    A     B      2009   2010   2011   2012   2013    2014
1     A     B        2      3.     2.     3.      
2     A     C        2      2.     2.     2.      2.     3 
3     A     C        3      3.     3.     4.      
4     A     E                                      3.     4 
5     A     B                      8      9        8.     9
```

Edit: fixed df data. Secondly One issue I notice is when I merge, my data A, and B, are duplicated, A_X, A_Y, A_Z, B_X, B_Y, B_Z
thank you in advance

Comment: are you sure your data is correct?

Comment: Why there is a  `4.     5` in the columns 2013, 2014?

Comment: fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the result.

But the code for merging will be like this:

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]

df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['ID'],
                                            how='outer'), dfs)
```

---

**df_merged:**

```
    ID  2009  2010  2011    2012    2013  2014
0   1   2.0   3.0   2.0     3.0     NaN   NaN
1   2   3.0   4.0   3.0     4.0     2.0   3.0
2   3   4.0   5.0   4.0     5.0     NaN   NaN
3   4   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     3.0   4.0
4   5   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     8.0   9.0
```

---

Edit:

Just use `on=['ID', 'A', 'B']`

**output:**

```
    ID  A   B   2009 2010 2011  2012 2013 2014
0   1   A   B   2.0  3.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
1   2   A   C   2.0  2.0  2.0   2.0  2.0  3.0
2   3   A   B   3.0  3.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
3   3   A   C   NaN  NaN  3.0   4.0  NaN  NaN
4   5   A   B   NaN  NaN  8.0   9.0  8.0  9.0
5   4   A   E   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: hi, I edited my question and table to fit more of what I;m doing, I'm noticing when I use your code, and merging columns A, B gets duplicated in the result data frame as A_x, A_y, A_z.

Comment: I'm getting an error for updating dattime64[ns], assume columns A, or B is date time, how should I proceed?

Comment: hm....what can I do regard columns A, and B if its date?

Answer (score 1):

Try `pd.concat([df.set_index('ID') for df in [df1, df2, df3]], axis=1).reset_index()`

The list comprehension sets `ID` as the index of each dataframe. Then we concatenate horizontally. Horizontal concatenation tries to match up the indexes where possible, otherwise it adds rows. Finally, we reset the index.

Comment: My A, B columns are being duplicated across the concatnenation and it shows up 3 times?

Comment: @Leo Not sure what your column names are, but use `set_index(['ID', 'A', 'B'])` in that case?